# R services in SQL server - since which version?

Tags: sql-server, r

Since which version does SQL server (non-Azure) support the R language?

What are good doc resources to get an overview of that support?

Comment: Are you sure information from the first question is not documented in the official documentation?

Comment: As of SQL Server 2016

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can be answered from Microsoft's marketing documentation and/or a Google search

Answer (score 4, accepted):

R Services was [introduced in SQL Server 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/what-s-new-in-sql-server-2016). The SQL Server 2017 version under development, adds support for Python and renamed the feature to [Machine Learning Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/what-s-new-in-sql-server-machine-learning-services).